# Maximal number of vertices of the intersection of a flat and a hypercube

Tags: discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry

Consider the intersection of an $n$-dimensional hybercube and an $m$-dimensional flat (affine subspace) which contains the diagonal of the hypercube. This is a convex polytope. What is the maximal number of vertices this polytope can have, for given $n$ and $m$? I would be satisfied with a decent upper bound.

EDIT: Here's the sketch of a proof that $\binom{n}{m}2^m$ is an upper bound, for any $m$-flat intersecting the hypercube (not just those containing the diagonal). A "generic" $m$-flat intersecting the hypercube intersects each $(n-m)$-face in at most one point. These intersections are the vertices of our polytope. Therefore, their number is bounded by the number of $(n-m)$-faces of the hypercube, which is the above expression. Moreover, the number of vertices of the intersection is a lower semincontinuous function of the flat (as long as it's constrained to intersect the hypercube), therefore this upper bound applies to non-generic cases as well.

However, this upper bound feels not so tight, even disregarding the constraint that the flat contains the diagonal. Because, if $m$ is much lower than $n$, it seems hard to intersect a large fraction of the $(n-m)$-faces at once.

Comment: The easy answers would be those for extremal m, that is for m=n (which yields #=2^n) and for m=1 (which yields #=2).

Comment: The answer is likely to be neater if you relax "containing the diagonal" to "containing the center of the hypercube". Indeed, polytopes which appear as a section of the n-hypercube through the center are exactly centrally symmetric polytopes with at most 2n facets. So, what you want is essentially the centrally symmetric version of the upper bound theorem: given dimension and facet number, how many vertices can a centrally symmetric polytope have? Here is a paper which looks relevant: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.09310

Comment: @GuillaumeAubrun Are you saying that *any* centrally symmetric polytope with at most 2n facets is a central section of the n-hypercube (at least up to combinatorial isomorphism)? Can you explain why / give a reference?

Comment: Yes. An origin-symmetric polytope $P$ in $\mathbf{R}^d$ with $2n$ facets is the intersection of the $n$ strips $\{ x \in \mathbf{R}^d \, ; \, |f_i(x)| \leq 1 \}$, where $f_i$ are linear forms. If you consider the injective linear map $f : \mathbf{R}^d \to \mathbf{R}^n$ given by $f=(f_1,\dots,f_n)$, then $P$ is isomoprhic to the section of $[-1,1]^n$ by the flat equal to the range of $f$.